# Resultado inválido al hacer consulta para un rango de fechas

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, plsql

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Al realizar una búsqueda de registros por rango de fechas con minutos con el siguiente formato `DD/MM/YY HH:MI`, esto del lado de Oracle, y al ejecutar el siguiente código obtengo fechas que no van acorde al rango seleccionado. Anexo mi código:

```
public List<Datos> getDatosFecs(String fechaIni, String fechaFin){

    System.out.println("Llegando fechas ::: Fecha inicio "+fechaIni+" ::: Fecha final "+fechaFin);
    List<Datos> datos = null;
    CallableStatement sentencia = null;
    int codigoError = -4;
    String respuesta = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    DateFormat forma = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
    java.util.Date dateIni = null, dateFin = null;
    boolean ok = false;
    try {
        dateIni = forma.parse(fechaIni);
        dateFin = forma.parse(fechaFin);
        System.out.println("Fechas obtenidas con java.util.Date ::: "+dateIni +" ::: "+dateFin);
        System.out.println("Fechas obtenidas con java.sql.Date ::: "+new Timestamp(dateIni.getTime()) +" ::: "+new Timestamp(dateFin.getTime()));
        ok = true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(ok){
        try{
            sb.append("{ call ");
            sb.append(esquema);
            sb.append(".MI_NOMBRE(?,?,?,?,?) }");
            sentencia = getCon().prepareCall(sb.toString());
            sentencia.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(dateIni.getTime()));
            sentencia.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(dateFin.getTime()));
            sentencia.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            sentencia.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
            sentencia.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            log.info("Antes de ejecutar el sp MI_NOMBRE");
            sentencia.execute();
            log.info("Despues de ejecutar MI_NOMBRE");
            codigoError = sentencia.getInt(4);
            respuesta = sentencia.getString(5);
            if(codigoError == 0){
                datos = new ArrayList<Datos>();
                rs = (ResultSet)sentencia.getObject(3);
                while(rs.next()){
                    Datos dat = new Datos();
                    dat.setCliente(rs.getString(1));
                    dat.setDestino(rs.getString(2));
                    Date date = forma.parse(rs.getString(3));
                    dat.setAlta(date);
                    datos.add(dat);
                }
            }else{
                log.info("Algo salio mal ::: "+respuesta);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }finally{
            cerrarConexion(rs, sentencia, getCon());
        }
    }
    return datos;
}
```

Más código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    datos();

}

public static void datos(){
    String fechaIni = "14/12/16 11:20", fechaFin = "20/12/16 14:20";
    Manejo man;
    try {
         man = new Manejo();
         List<Datos> datos = man.getDatosFecs(fechaIni, fechaFin);
         if(datos.isEmpty()){

         }else{
             for(Datos dat : datos){
                 System.out.println("CLIENTE ::: "+dat.getCliente());
                 System.out.println("DESTINO ::: "+dat.getDestino());
                 System.out.println("ALTA ::: "+dat.getAlta());
             }
         }
    } catch (DatabaseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Mi SP:

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ESQUEMA.MI_NOMBRE(
VL_FEC_INI IN ESQUEMA.TABLA.FECHA_MODIFICACION%TYPE,
VL_FEC_FIN IN ESQUEMA.TABLA.FECHA_MODIFICACION%TYPE,
VL_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
VL_COD_ERROR OUT NUMBER,
VL_MSJ_ERROR OUT VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ''DD/MM/YY HH24:MI'' ';
  OPEN VL_CURSOR FOR
      SELECT TER.CLIENTE, TER.DESTINO, TO_CHAR(TER.FECHA_MODIFICACION, 'DD/MM/YY HH:MI') FROM ESQUEMA.TABLA TER
      WHERE TO_CHAR(TER.FECHA_MODIFICACION, 'DD/MM/YY HH:MI') >= TO_CHAR(VL_FEC_INI, 'DD/MM/YY HH:MI') AND TO_CHAR(TER.FECHA_MODIFICACION, 'DD/MM/YY HH:MI') <= TO_CHAR(VL_FEC_FIN, 'DD/MM/YY HH:MI');
    VL_COD_ERROR:=0;
    VL_MSJ_ERROR:='REGISTROS OBTENIDOS SATISFACTORIAMENTE';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      VL_COD_ERROR:=-1;
      VL_MSJ_ERROR:=SQLCODE || ' ' || SQLERRM;
END MI_NOMBRE;
```

Al ejecutarlo obtengo lo siguiente:

```
    Llegando fechas ::: Fecha inicio 14/12/16 11:20 ::: Fecha final 20/12/16 14:20
Fechas obtenidas con java.util.Date ::: Wed Dec 14 11:20:00 CST 2016 ::: Tue Dec 20 14:20:00 CST 2016
Fechas obtenidas con java.sql.Date ::: 2016-12-14 11:20:00.0 ::: 2016-12-20 14:20:00.0
CLIENTE ::: 42596931
CUENTA ::: 5204164920198691
ALTA ::: Tue Jun 20 01:49:00 CDT 2017
CLIENTE ::: 45840223
CUENTA ::: 00560100031180
ALTA ::: Thu May 18 06:16:00 CDT 2017
CLIENTE ::: 50808037
CUENTA ::: 27111111111117
ALTA ::: Tue Sep 19 12:00:00 CDT 2017
CLIENTE ::: 29315905
CUENTA ::: 01000184749252
ALTA ::: Tue Oct 17 09:42:00 CDT 2017
CLIENTE ::: 29315905
CUENTA ::: 5256786036715799
ALTA ::: Mon Dec 18 01:56:00 CST 2017
CLIENTE ::: 29315905
CUENTA ::: 5541387606
ALTA ::: Mon Dec 18 01:56:00 CST 2017
CLIENTE ::: 45840223
CUENTA ::: 06730100031629
ALTA ::: Thu Jul 20 12:00:00 CDT 2017
CLIENTE ::: 52970866
CUENTA ::: 06731300007283
ALTA ::: Sun Dec 17 04:51:00 CST 2017
CLIENTE ::: 3426679
CUENTA ::: 27111111111117
ALTA ::: Tue Sep 19 12:00:00 CDT 2017
CLIENTE ::: 29315905
CUENTA ::: 014180655024150941
ALTA ::: Mon Dec 18 01:56:00 CST 2017
CLIENTE ::: 55732458
CUENTA ::: 5567760853
ALTA ::: Mon Dec 18 10:27:00 CST 2017
CLIENTE ::: 29315905
CUENTA ::: 014320655030560466
ALTA ::: Mon Dec 18 02:01:00 CST 2017
CLIENTE ::: 29315905
CUENTA ::: 00560100031180
ALTA ::: Thu Nov 16 12:13:00 CST 2017
CLIENTE ::: 44786371
CUENTA ::: 01720197744590
ALTA ::: Thu Oct 17 05:54:00 CDT 2002
CLIENTE ::: 45840223
CUENTA ::: 2135468797
ALTA ::: Thu May 18 06:15:00 CDT 2017
CLIENTE ::: 1140043
CUENTA ::: 5567760853
ALTA ::: Sun Nov 19 04:13:00 CST 2017
CLIENTE ::: 45840223
CUENTA ::: 27111111111117
ALTA ::: Tue Sep 19 12:00:00 CDT 2017
```

Como pueden ver, obtengo fechas que no están dentro del rango que estoy buscando, o sea del 14 al 20 de diciembre 2016. ¿Alguna idea del por qué pasa esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón porque esto sucede es debido a tus condiciones en la consulta dentro de tu procedimiento:

```sql
SELECT TER.CLIENTE,
       TER.DESTINO,
       TO_CHAR(TER.FECHA_MODIFICACION, 'DD/MM/YY HH:MI')
  FROM ESQUEMA.TABLA TER
 WHERE TO_CHAR(TER.FECHA_MODIFICACION, 'DD/MM/YY HH:MI') >= TO_CHAR(VL_FEC_INI, 'DD/MM/YY HH:MI')
  AND TO_CHAR(TER.FECHA_MODIFICACION, 'DD/MM/YY HH:MI') <= TO_CHAR(VL_FEC_FIN, 'DD/MM/YY HH:MI');
```

En particular, el problema es que estás convirtiendo las fechas a cadenas de formato `DD/MM/YY HH:MI`, y usando esas cadenas en ese formato para efectuar las comparaciones. Esto es un grave error, porque quiere decir que **estás haciendo una comparación *alfanumérica* en vez de una comparación por fechas.**

Esto explica porqué te devuelve valores como `Tue Jun 20 01:49:00 CDT 2017`. Porque haciendo la comparación ***alfanumérica*** usando el formato `DD/MM/YY HH:MI`, viene siendo:

```sql
where '20/06/17 01:49' >= '14/12/16 11:20'
and   '20/06/17 01:49' <= '20/12/16 02:20'
```

...que, nuevamente, desde un punto de vista alfanumérico, entonces ambas condiciones son ciertas, aunque la fecha es obviamente incorrecta.

La solución es eliminar los `TO_CHAR` de las condiciones para que las comparaciones se hagan con las fechas directamente:

```sql
SELECT TER.CLIENTE,
       TER.DESTINO,
       TO_CHAR(TER.FECHA_MODIFICACION, 'DD/MM/YY HH:MI')
  FROM ESQUEMA.TABLA TER
 WHERE TER.FECHA_MODIFICACION >= VL_FEC_INI
  AND  TER.FECHA_MODIFICACION <= VL_FEC_FIN;
```

---

Nota adicional: Aunque en mi respuesta me centro en tu problema específico, realmente veo que en todas partes en tu código te estás armando un rollo con la forma como conviertes las fechas a cadenas y de vuelta a fechas sin razón aparente en muchos casos. Sería bueno simplificar el código, y tratar de usar fechas con los tipos apropiados siempre que sea posible.

Es más, aun en los casos raros donde tal vez necesites manipular fechas con cadenas, evita usar formatos ambiguos como `DD/MM/YY HH:MI` que fácilmente se pueden malinterpretar y te puede causar otros problemas. Favorece mas bien formatos mas "estables" como `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`, o algo por el estilo.

Comment: Hola, al realizar la consulta de la forma en que lo indicas no obtengo resultado alguno, obtengo el siguiente error 01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"; el por qué manejo en este formato, es por que así lo pide quien lo va usar, también pensé que sería mejor en la forma que lo indicas, saludos.

Comment: ¿Cual es el tipo de `ESQUEMA.TABLA.FECHA_MODIFICACION`? Lo estás usando como si fuera de tipo fecha, pero por el error, suena a que tal vez no es del tipo correcto. Eso sería triste.

Comment: Es tipo Date, intentare más cosas, gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: Seguro usastes la consulta tal como te la puse, o le agregastes un `TO_DATE` en alguna parte?  Porque ese error que mencionas usualmente solo sucede cuando intentas convertir una cadena a una fecha, y la consulta que te propuse no hace eso en ninguna parte.

Comment: La use tal cual la pusiste y no retorna dato alguno, como bien mencionas le agregue un TO_DATE y es cuando obtengo el error menciona arriba, pero como tal pusiste la consulta no me retorna registros, lo cual esta mal, dado que si tengo registros en las fechas que le indico :(

Comment: Menos mal que pregunté. Con tu comentario por claro, me hubieras dejado con la duda de cómo pudo esta consulta generar el error. Ahora bien, si el tipo de la columna `ESQUEMA.TABLA.FECHA_MODIFICACION` realmente es `Date`, entonces la consulta que te puse definitivamente es la correcta. Para verificar los datos, ejecuta la consulta siguiente directamente en la base de datos y dime que resultado obtienes: `select count(*) from ESQUEMA.TABLA where FECHA_MODIFICACION between to_date('2016-12-14 11:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') and to_date('2016-12-20 14:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')`.

Comment: Obtengo un registro de 0, al parecer no hay registros en esas fechas, amplié un poco más el rango de fechas(hasta el 22-dic) y obtengo registros. Al parecer solo era el rango de fechas. gracias por el apoyo.